# How do I reference javax classes with Haxe?

Tags: java, swing, haxe

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877474/haxe-java-windowing) answer (which is a few years old), it should be straightforward to refer to Swing classes from Haxe and it should Just Work™. But, when I clone the [referenced gist](https://gist.github.com/cambiata/d025fc7e66352a0b0681) and try to build it, it says there is an error:

> Main.hx:4: characters 7-25 : Type not found : javax.swing.JPanel

I can refer to anything in `java.*` and it seems to work just fine.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `java.javax.swing.JPanel` instead of `javax.swing.JPanel`.